# Background not showing javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create a start screen in javaFX and add a background to it to go behind the button and the text. It does not seem to work for me however, as the background doe not appear for my app. Would like to know what is wrong. Here is my code:

```
package calendar;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class Calendar extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {



primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Welcome");
GridPane grid = new GridPane();
grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
grid.setHgap(10);
grid.setVgap(10);
grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));

Text scenetitle = new Text("Get Started");
scenetitle.setFont(Font.font("Bookman", FontWeight.BOLD, 30));
grid.add(scenetitle, 0, 0, 2, 1);

Button start = new Button("Start");
HBox hbStart = new HBox(10);
hbStart.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
hbStart.getChildren().add(start);
grid.add(hbStart, 1, 10);

final Text actiontarget = new Text();
grid.add(actiontarget, 1, 6);

start.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent e) {

  }
});       

Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 800, 600);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
scene.getStylesheets().add
 (Calendar.class.getResource("background.css").toExternalForm());
primaryStage.show();
 }

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

The code for the css file is as follows:

```
 .root { -fx-background-image: url("background.jpeg"); }
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am fairly certain that this is not a problem with me misplacing or misnaming the file.

Comment: I dont think you are loading your css correctly, try chaging: `scene.getStylesheets().add
  (Calendar.class.getResource("background.css").toExternalForm());` To: `scene.getStylesheets().add("background.css");`

Comment: @luckydog32 I think that he's loaded the css correctly.
May be there's some problem in the css file. James Latimer, could you please share you css code

Comment: .root {
         -fx-background-image: url("background.jpeg");
    }

Comment: Please don't post code in comments; edit your question to include additional information in response to comments. (You might like to fix the [formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) while you are there.) Judging by the resource name you are using for the CSS file, the CSS is in the `calendar` package; the string you provide to the `url(...)` CSS function will [resolve relative to the CSS resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typeurl), so `background.jpeg` needs to be in the same package.

Comment: Right sorry about that.  Also I'm quite sure the picture is contained in the same directory as the css and Java file,  I just located the directory on my computer and added the picture their.